# CO2 impact and offset by tree planting calculations: inference and data

Tags: environment

Suppose CO2 emissions are such that factory growth is on the increase, and trees, are either in slow increase or decrease.

Suppose, this occurs at a global level, and CO2 flows easily between nations so that it does not matter where the trees are planted.

Suppose we do not know whether CO2 emissions travel up, down (trees could be planted high up in buildings), or whether CO2 flows across the globe (such as with wind), and how far the CO2 goes (diffusion (and, perhaps, globally constraintly constant air composition percentages) could play a role, here).

If factories grow, then we should be able to predict (using statistical prediction techniques), based on factory growth rate, the curve of CO2 emissions, globally, based on factory growth.

What is this curve?

Assuming we cannot control that, but we can control tree planting, and we have sites for tree planting, donations, can we graph the predictions, with one graph in which each prediction is made (for example, one for tree planting versus factory growth), each month?

That is, each month we have the prediction graph for tree growth in terms of number of trees and CO2 offset.

The prediction graph has time on the x-axis, and three graphs on the y-axis, which are, on the same scale, (1.) CO2 emitted (e.g. by factories) and (2.) absorbed by trees (taking into account tree growth, and, that initially, different trees may be small, and, thus, have a lower absorption rate, and, according to which trees are planted this may change (as some trees may develop faster or more powerful leaves, structure).

On the same graph, but with a difference scale on the y-axis, (3.) the prediction of number of trees planted, and how the painting is going (based on government contributions and the power of tree planting sites donations).

There might be even a protocol allowing the different tree-saving sites to communicate about this.

A large amount of trees may already be government protected, but we may need to pay to ensure ongoing support and have funds to ensure tree planting grows, and grows well, does not shrink, and money is available to sustain tree planting and protection to give it value.

Since trees take a while to grow, each prediction should have a break-off point where one sort of parabola (CO2 absorption) takes over factory emissions (CO2 emissions), as the trees planted, grow bigger (and, thus, start absorbing more).

Do we have this data anywhere?

Where can I find some of this data?

Here are two nice sites I found that plan and dea with CO2 emissions.

[Tree Nation](https://tree-nation.com/)

[TreeDom](https://www.treedom.net/it)

Thank you for your statistical contributions, including how statistic research is conducted to calculate the graphs I mentioned.

Please migrate my post to the Open Data Stack Exchange if more appropriate there.

Thanks.

Comment: One problem is that the Earth is covered by oceans, not trees, and water born algae consume carbon dioxide. Next problem, there is much more carbon dioxide in Earth's water than in the air. Next, warm soda pop fizzes. That is, when the oceans warm even a little bit, it releases massive amounts of carbon dioxide. Finally, global warming causes increased atmospheric carbon dioxide, and carbon dioxide plays no appreciable role in moderating Earth's temperature because carbon dioxide absorbs very little sunlight or heat, and there is too little of it in the atmosphere to matter.